# matches class-validator decorator not working for type-graphql auto validation

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typegraphql

I'm trying to use class validator for validatin my inputtype in type-graphql but the @mathes decorator, is not working, All other decorators with suffix 'Is' are working, but not this one.

```
const mobileNumberRegex = /^(\+[0-9]{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{9,10}$/;

@Field()
@Matches(mobileNumberRegex)
mobileNumber!: string;
```

I'm expecting error when the mobile number is not working, but it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Although not knowing why `@Matches` doesn't work you could try the `@IsMobilePhone(locale: string)` and the `@IsPhoneNumber(region: string)` decorators which could even be a more elegant solution